# Use of template <class T> in C++ when declaring classes and functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am quite new to the topic of templates in C++. Why in the following toy example code do we have to precede the class's and each function's name with `template <class T>` (meaning why do we need it, at all)?

Is it possible to modify the code not to use `template <class T>` everywhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack {   private:
    vector<T> elements;

  public:
    void push(T const &);
    void pop();
    T top();
    bool empty(); };

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T const &elem) {
    elements.push_back(elem); }

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (elements.empty()) {
        throw out_of_range("Stack<>::pop(): empty stack");
    } else {
        elements.pop_back();
    }
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::top() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw out_of_range("Stack<>::top(): empty stack");
    }
    return elements.back();
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() {
    return elements.empty();
}


int main() {
    try {
        Stack<int> intStack;       // Stack of ints
        Stack<string> stringStack; // Stack of strings

        // Manipulate integer stack
        intStack.push(7);
        cout << intStack.top() << endl;

        // Manipulate string stack
        stringStack.push("hello");
        cout << stringStack.top() << std::endl;
        stringStack.pop();
        stringStack.pop();
    }
    catch (exception const &ex) {
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "template header"?

Comment: There are no headers for template. If you don't want to use template the define two class for two different data types `std::string` and `int`.

Comment: By "template header" I mean `template <class T> `. How should I call it then? I said I'm new to the topic. Please be more understandable.

Comment: @cerebrou Yes you can do that by replacing all occurences of `T` with a concrete type like `int` or `double`. But why would you want to do so? It makes the class less useful.

Comment: New to the topic of templates in C++? Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: Q: "Why do we have to precede the class's and each function's name with `template <class T>`"? A: Because that's the syntax for templates. Q: What are templates, why do we need them, and how do we use them? A: This is too broad here.

Comment: @bolov what part of the OP's question makes you think they are asking the second, and not the first?

Comment: @Caleth The OP is asking for the first. But that answer to that is "because that's how you declare template" and then I feel like this just slides into question 2. It's like asking why do we write `int a = 5`. The answer is because that's how we declare a variable, and then of course it comes: "Ok, now please explain what are variables"

Comment: OP also asks "can I write this template without N+1 copies of `template <class T>`, for N members", which *isn't* "please explain templates"

Comment: I believe the question is not too brad at all. The OP is not familiar with the inline method implementations (implementation inside class), and he/she just noticed that the the "usual" way of defining the methods has a lot of repetitive syntax in the case of templates. Asking how to get rid of that syntax is pretty legitimate.

Comment: @Caleth: You are referring to a different revision of the question than others are. That one *may* be more reasonable. The first incarnation certainly was just a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I saw the first incarnation, which I didn't think was a waste of time. I thought it needed some clarity of terminology

Answer (score 12):

C++ is a [statically typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language.

Since this is the case, say I wanted a function to check the minimum or maximum of two values.

I could create a function like the following:

```
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

But this only works for `int` types. If I want one for a `double` or `uint64_t` or `FooBarClass`, I would need to create additional functions:

```
double max(double a, double b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
uint64_t max(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
FooBarClass max(FooBarClass a, FooBarClass b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

> Why in the following toy example code do we have to precede the class's and each function's name with template ?

In C++, a `template` is a way to introduce a concept known as ["generics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). With generics, you no longer need to concern your self with creating a function for each type, the type will be deduced from the template function signature.

So instead, I could write the following:

```
template < typename T > // the typename or class keywords are synonymous when declaring a template
T max(T a, T b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

The inclusion of `template < typename T >` to the function signature indicates to the compiler that this function is a "generic" function and must be processed accordingly.

If, on the other hand, you just had the following:

```
T max(T a, T b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

The compiler will expect `T` to be an explicit type (like `typedef int T;`).

A template can be applied to a class or function, and both at the same time:

```
template < typename T >
class Wrapper {
    public:
        Wrapper(const T& val) : _val(val) {}
        // ... other code

        template < typename X >
        operator X()
        {
            return static_cast<X>(this->_val);
        }

        T operator+(const T& val)
        {
            return this->_val + val;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Wrapper& val)
        {
            os << val._val;
            return os;
        }

    private:
        T _val;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Wrapper<int> x(42);
    // template deduction will call Wrapper::operator X() with X being a double
    double d = x;
    // template deduction will call Wrapper::operator X() with X being a long
    long l = x;
    // this actually calls T operator+(const T& val) with val = 10 and T = int
    int i = x + 10;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl  // 42
              << "d = " << d << std::endl  // 42
              << "l = " << l << std::endl  // 42
              << "i = " << i << std::endl; // 52
    return 0;
}
```

You can also explicitly define a template type, this is known as [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)
and is beyond the scope of this answer given your understanding of templates at the current.

> Is it possible to modify the code not to use template  everywhere?

Yes and no. Yes, you can remove the `template < class T >` signature definition, but, as mentioned, the signature of the class/function takes on a completely different meaning.

Hope that clears up a little bit. Templates, when used properly, are a very powerful tool in C++.

Comment: C++ is *statically typed*, not *"strongly typed"*. It allows for implicit conversions, that can be lossy.

Answer (score 5):

You have to include `template <class T>` in each member definition because that is part of the name of the member.

You can define the functions within the class-template body, for only one line with `template <class T>`

```
template <class T> 
class Stack {   
  private:
    vector<T> elements;

  public:
    void push(T const &) {
      elements.push_back(elem); }
    void pop() {
      if (elements.empty()) {
          throw out_of_range("Stack<>::pop(): empty stack");
      } else {
          elements.pop_back();
      } }
    T top() {
      if (empty()) {
          throw out_of_range("Stack<>::top(): empty stack");
      }
      return elements.back(); }
    bool empty() {
      return elements.empty(); } };
```